# ¿Hay alguna forma de subir imágenes a WP?

Tags: nodejs, woocommerce

¿Como podría subir una imagen para un producto mediante un api nodejs? Estoy desarrollando un servicio con NodeJs con el que mediante el API de Woocommerce creo, actualizo, veo y elimino tanto pedidos, como clientes y productos de una tienda de Woocommerce. El caso es que no encuentro la manera de subir una imagen para cada producto. He estado investigando, y no encuentro la manera. ¿Alguna idea?
El API de woocommerce no dispone de esa funcionalidad.

Comment: Para entender un poco mejor, tienes un servicio con NodeJs que se conecta a un servicio de Wordpress? Es decir una especie de servicio proxy? Por otro lado te pregunto, no tienes forma de programar directamente desde Wordpress?

Comment: Es un servicio de nodejs alojado en un servidor. Mediante este servicio, me conecto a la API de Woocommerce para realizar las operaciones CRUD para clientes, productos y pedidos. Mediante este API puedo realizar esta operaciones fácilmente. El problema es que no encuentro una forma de subir esas imágenes. No sé si se necesita algo de información en concreto. El caso sería subir la imagen al servidor y luego actualizar la propiedad imágenes del producto en cuestión. El caso es que este servicio de NodeJS lo gestiones todo, pero si hay otras maneras me gustaría saberlas.

Comment: Yo en nodejs no ando puesto, pero si te puedo decir que si conoces el usuario y la contraseña te puedes conectar al servidor del cliente desde PHP. Puedes subir el archivo y actualizar la BD de wordpress donde están los artículos con el nombre y ruta de la foto subida. Sería externo a nodejs, pero se puede hacer. La otra es hacerlo manualmente en wordpress. Quizá alguien sepa otras formas. Si quieres mas explicación sobre el tema avísame y te comento.

Comment: Puedes poner tu solución como respuesta y darle como aceptada. Así los demás usuarios que entren podrán localizarla mas fácilmente. Un saludo.

Comment: El titulo de tu pregunta es muy amplio, la respuesta corta y exacta sería: **Sí, si hay, y no alguna sino muchas**. Yo en tu lugar la limitaría al problema en especifico. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, si hay solución, y hay varias, aquí presento una de ellas:

He encontrado una solución, que de momento, es válida. Se trata de utilizar el cliente de JavaScript: "wordpress", XML-RCP Wordpress API.

```
const wp = require('wordpress'),
    wpClient = wp.createClient({
        url: 'http://xxxxx/xxxxxx',
        username: "xxxxxx",
        password: "xxxxxx"
    });
```

Una vez tenemos el cliente podremos proceder a procesar la imagen y utilizar el método "uploadFile". Se puede obtener la documentación de esto en:

https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API o en https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress

Que quede claro que la API Promises de FyleSystem de NodeJS está en fase experimental.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
let fsPromises = require("fs").promises;    
let imageData =  await fsPromises.readFile("ruta de la imagen");
                wpClient.uploadFile({
                    name: "nombreDeImage.jpg",
                    type: "image/jpeg",
                    bits: imageData
                }, (error, file) => {
                    if(error){console.log(error);}
                    console.log(file);
                });
```

Obtenemos los datos de la imagen mediante fsPromises.readFile() y lo que obtenemos lo situaremos en la propiedad bits. Con esto deberíamos de haber subido la imagen. Se devolverá entre otros datos la URL de la imagen dentro de la propiedad "link" una vez subida, y esta se puede utilizar para actualizar la propiedad "images" del producto, por ejemplo. Espero que haya quedado claro, si se necesita alguna explicación más que nadie dude en consultar. Un saludo.